# Why is SP.js is not registering for Anonymous Users?

Tags: javascript, 2013

In SharePoint 2013 I tried:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { alert("Hi"); }, 'SP.js');
```

But SP.js is not registering for anonymous users.

Answer (score 1):

SP.js is a file that is only loaded when called. Mostly. Otherwise if users have access to certain ribbon commands which loads it.

Try calling SP.js in your application and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks Dandroid for the replay and i tested it when i edit the page I can see that SP.JS is registering. But my main concern is for anonymous user so Are there any way to do it for anonymous user?

Comment: @Hitman Register the SP.js file in your masterpage. That way it is loaded on each page using that masterpage and then it doesn't if the user is anonymous or not.